# Ignore directories passed as arguments in ARGF

Tags: ruby

I want to write a script that does some work on some files specified on a command line, but I want the user to be able to call

```
fooscript *
```

even if * expands to include some directory names

I know I can use ARGF to handle the files

```
ARGF.each do |f|
    puts f
end
```

But this gives me an error for the case of a directory.  I'd like to skip over directoryies, or perhaps handle them specially.  What's the most idiomatic way to accomplish this is Ruby?

Comment: What error it gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just filter them from `ARGV` before reading `ARGF` :

```
ARGV.reject! {|f| File.directory? f }

# Now there are no dirs in ARGF...
ARGF.each do |l|
  #... etc.
```

Comment: That sounds like just what I'm looking for -- neophyte rubist that I am.  I'll check it out soon.